# Wordpress multi-query not returning as expected

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, php

I am trying to perform a merged query to get *at most* 6 posts from either the `post` post type and my `events` custom post type. The `post` query is based off of whether or not the Featured Image is set, and the `events` query is based off of whether or not the post has the meta value *Featured* selected. Everything works except: **The query only returns 5 posts, and they are not balanced in the sense that [depending on which post I set as Featured/Add Featured Image too] they take precedence over one another.**

For Example: If I add a Featured Image to a `post` post the results will be *3 event, 2 post*. If I then check the Featured meta value in an `events` post type the results will be *4 event, 1 post*.

Here is the code I am using to query and return posts:

```
        <?php
        $post_types = get_post_types('','names');
        $featuredEvents = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'events',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'showposts' => 6,
            'meta_key' => '_ecmb_featured_event',
            'meta_value' => 'on'
        ));
        $featuredNews = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'showposts' => 6,
            'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'
        ));
        $mergedPosts = array_merge( $featuredEvents, $featuredNews );
        $postIDs = array();
            foreach( $mergedPosts as $item ) {
            $postIDs[] = $item->ID;
        }
        $uniquePosts = array_unique($postIDs);

        $posts = get_posts(array(
            'post__in' => $uniquePosts,
            'post_type' => $post_types,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        ));

        foreach( $posts as $post ) :
        setup_postdata($post);
        if( get_post_type() == 'events' ) { ?>
                    This is a Featured Event
        <?php } elseif (get_post_type() == 'post') { ?>
                    This a post with the Featured Image set
        <?php } endforeach; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Can someone help me with this?

**Edit:**

Thanks to the answer below, I figured it out and used the following code:

```
$sliderQueryArgs = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type' => array(
        'post',
        'events'
    ),
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => '_ecmb_featured_event',
                'value' => 'on'),
            array(
                'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS')
    )
);

$sliderPosts = get_posts( $sliderQueryArgs );
```

Comment: Can you describe the results you want from these queries? What do you mean by "balanced" and which query _should_ take precedence, for example?

Comment: Good point — ideally it would be a 3/3 split, with either post type filling in when there aren't enough to meet the 3. On another note, it would be great if I could combine the two post types to display in order published, rather than all event posts first, then all post posts. But I won't push my luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the fact that `get_posts()` (or `WP_Query`) can take an `array()` of post types in a singular query. [More info on Type Parameters in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters). The order will per default be the publishing date.

You can then specify it further by adding in stuff like your `taxonomy_query`, etc.

Keep in mind that you can `orderby` by `meta_value` as well as assigning multiple `orderby` arguments space separated:

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value post_date'
```

for example.

Comment: Thank you! Check out my edit above to see what I ended up doing.

Comment: @JodyHeavener Please add that as an answer and mark it as solution. If you don't feel comfortable with that, simply [edit] my answer and fill in the missing bits. Thanks.